# Regex for word.otherword

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want a Regular Expression for a word.otherword form. I tried `\b[a-z]\.[a-z]\b`, but it gives me an error at the `\.` part, saying `Unrecognized escape sequence`. Any idea what's wrong? I'm working under .NET C#. Thanks!

LE:

`john.Smith` or `JoHn.SmItH` or `JOHN.SMITH` should work.

`John Smith` or `john!Smith` or `john.Smith.Smith` shouldn't work.

Comment: Do you want the words to be identical or is word simply a place holder for any words?

Comment: The words don't have to be identical. Any alphabetical sequence will do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(SubjectString, @"\b[a-z]\.[a-z]\b");
```

Probably you were not using @?

Your regex tries to match a.a this means a single character. But since you want it to match complete words you need a quantifier e.g.

```
\b[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\b
```

Finally you may want to use the case insensitive match to allow for words with capital letters to be matched too :

```
foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(SubjectString, @"\b[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This will match all words.words with at least one character for each word regardless of capitalization.

This will match all word.otherword only if there is a space behind the first word or it is the start of the string and only if there is a space after the second word or it is the end of the string.

```
foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(SubjectString, @"(?<=\s|^)\b[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\b(?=\s|$)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: I wasn't using @. Now it doesn't give me an error anymore, but the regex still doesn't work in the word.word form.

Comment: @AdrianMar: Check Aziz's answer.

Comment: @FailedDev Thanks so much! It works. Only one thing wrong. In the second word, I want only letters, and the above regex accepts other characters too.

Comment: @AdrianMar I find this rather hard to believe since we are specifically accepting characters in the range a-z. Can you edit your question with a sample input and an expected output?

Comment: @FailedDev I don't want spaces, but what about this RegEx `@"^[a-z]+\.[a-z]+$"`? It seems to work.

Comment: @AdrianMar Yes it works if you want to match a string in its entirety. My regex also matches this.that that.this lol.me in one line and not in separate strings.

Comment: @FailedDev Yes, I want it in its entirety, only one word.otherword, not more. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex for `word.word` format:

```
@"\b([a-z]+)\.\1"
```

For `word.otherword` use this:

```
@"\b[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\b"
```

Comment: This looks like the correct answer if the OP is looking for actually word.word and NOT word.someotherword. So using back references is the correct way.

Comment: I agree. Although my answer was based on the fact that he didn't mention that the words should be identical. I though word meant merely a placeholder for any word.

Comment: Sorry about that. The form I want is word.otherword

Comment: @FailedDev: Agreed :) That's what I wanted to clarify as well.

Comment: In the second word (otherword), I want only letters, and the above regex accepts other characters too, such as numbers, symbols etc.

Comment: That is strange. I don't see any reason why it would accept numbers, etc. The regex clearly mentions to accept only alphabets from a-z. There could be an error somewhere else.